# I want pass the data from vc2 to vc1 with closer by use of table array

Tags: ios, swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
var array = [(String, String, String, String)]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstTVC", for: indexPath) as! FirstTVC
    cell.lblFirst.text = array[indexPath.row].0
    cell.lblName.text = array[indexPath.row].1
    cell.lblContact.text = array[indexPath.row].2
    cell.lblAddress.text = array[indexPath.row].3
    return cell
    
}
@IBAction func btnDone(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let cont = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondVC
    cont.objdata = {
        (str1,str2,str3,str4) in
        self.array.append((str1,str2,str3,str4))
        
    }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cont, animated: true)
}
```

}

import UIKit

class SecondVC: UIViewController {
typealias data = (String, String, String, String) -> Void
var objdata:data?

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtFldFirst: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtFldAddress: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtFldContact: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtFldName: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}
@IBAction func btnPush(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let finalSet = self.objdata else {
        return
    }
    finalSet(txtFldName.text!, txtFldAddress.text!, txtFldContact.text!, txtFldFirst.text!)
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    
}
```

}

Comment: "I want pass the data from vc2 to vc1 with closer by use of table array"  What is a guy named 'closer'?  The closure, you mean?

Comment: The code is basically supposed to work, you just need to reload the table view in the closure. But a tuple as model is a horrible practice.

Comment: yes, i mean closer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
   var tuuparry = [(String,String,String)] ()

    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func actionGoNext(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
        vc.objclassDatapass = {
            (strg1,strg2,strag3) in
            self.tuuparry.append((strg1,strg2,strag3))
            self.tblView.reloadData()
            
            
            
        }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tuuparry.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.lblName.text = tuuparry[indexPath.row].0
        cell.lblClass.text = tuuparry[indexPath.row].1
        cell.lblRoll.text = tuuparry[indexPath.row].2
        return cell
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the two of you working together asking / answering the same questions? Your questions seem to be almost identical, and your answers don't explain anything, just post code without using the formatting tools